# Best way to delete related columns with relationships

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, model, relationship

For example we have p_categories table and product table.

p_categories table is:

```
╔═══╦════════════╦═════════════╗
║   ║ id         ║ name        ║
╠═══╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1 ║ 1          ║ tech        ║
║ 2 ║ 2          ║ food        ║
║ 3 ║ 3          ║ sport       ║
╚═══╩════════════╩═════════════╝
```

products table is:

```
╔════╦═══════════════╦═════╗
║ id ║p_categories_id║name ║
╠════╬═══════════════╬═════╣
║ 1  ║ 1             ║phone║
╠════╬═══════════════╬═════╣
║ 2  ║ 2             ║spoon║
╠════╬═══════════════╬═════╣
║ 3  ║ 2             ║fork ║
╚════╩═══════════════╩═════╝
```

In the pcategory model i have:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'p_categories_id');
}
```

In the Product model:

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(PCategory::class,'p_categories_id', 'id');
}
```

When i try to delete tech category, in the `product table` `id=1, p_categories_id=1, name=phone` row must be deleted same time.

probably solutions i thought:

1) changing column types to cascade. I read some posts. People mostly don't recomend this.

2) in the category model adding a new function

```
protected static function boot() {
parent::boot();
static::deleting(//something, i don't know how to make.); }
```

I need to change whole project with this method. Because there isn't one. I am searching best way to do this. I wrote 2 probably solutions, but i am still don't know how to make them correctly. I hope I can explain myself, thank you in advance

Comment: Quick suggestion, in `products` table use `categories_id` not `p_categories_id`... As you stated you have option to use MySQL cascading and I do it this way (most of the time), if you read answers why not, share them here. You wrote "probably" solutions share them!

Comment: Just don't try to eat a spoon

Answer (score 1):

You must be use database foreign key constraint. For make db using laravel migration you can use

```
$table->foreign('p_categories_id')
      ->references('id')->on('p_categories ')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
```

see [https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#foreign-key-constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#foreign-key-constraints.)

Answer (score 1):

To use Eloquent events in the model you can do something like:

```
static::deleting(function (self $category) {
    $category->products()->delete();
});
```

If you need to trigger events on the products as well you will need to loop through the products and delete them one by one e.g.

```
$category->products->each(function ($product) {
    $product->delete();
});
```

The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#events) doesn't show the above method and instead favours using `Observers`, it does, however, show you which model events you have access to.

Comment: 1 categories could be have a lot of product rows in this situation. when i made $category->products->each->delete(); 
is nessesary to foreach? It work this way right?. I have delete function too.

Comment: Foreach is not needed because it's done for you behind the scenes, it's a higher order message https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#higher-order-messages

Comment: @AliÖzen I've updated my answer to try and make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try soon.